# Multiplying a Pandas column by a multi-index value

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I had a multi-index dataframe with three levels on index. I would like to multiply each Percent value by the total population.

I am trying something like this:

```
df = df.reset_index(level=2, drop=True)
df['TOTAL'] = df['POP.'] * output['PERCENT']
```

I get `KeyError: 'POP.'`

Starting DataFrame

```
                               PERCENT  
     DATE      POP.  SEX                
2015-01-01     100  MALE        0.51  
                    FEMALE      0.49  
2016-01-01     200  MALE        0.52  
                    FEMALE      0.48
```

Desired Output

```
                               PERCENT     TOTAL  
     DATE      POP.  SEX                
2015-01-01     100  MALE        0.51         51  
                    FEMALE      0.49         49
2016-01-01     200  MALE        0.52        104
                    FEMALE      0.48         96
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need `get_level_values` + `values`

```
df['TOTAL']=(df.index.get_level_values('POP')*df['PERCENT']).values
df
Out[874]: 
                       PERCENT  TOTAL
DATE       POP SEX                   
2015-01-01 100 MALE       0.51   51.0
               FEMALE     0.49   49.0
2016-01-01 120 Male       0.52   62.4
               FEMALE     0.48   57.6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `multiply` method and set `axis="index"` as follows:

```
df['TOTAL'] = df['POP'].multiply(df['PERCENT'], axis="index")
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [DataFrame.eval()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.eval.html) method:

```
In [118]: df = df.eval("TOTAL = PERCENT * POP", inplace=False)

In [119]: df
Out[119]:
                         PERCENT  TOTAL
DATE       POP   SEX
2015-01-01 100.0 MALE       0.51   51.0
                 FEMALE     0.49   49.0
2016-01-01 200.0 MALE       0.52  104.0
                 FEMALE     0.48   96.0
```